# How to add 'requireNativeComponent' to exports?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps, react-native-maps

This is my first ever React Native app. I am trying to use MapView from react-native-maps, but am running into this error: **"Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'."** I am viewing my app in web view (if that matters). I have installed and linked react-native-maps. Here is my current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And the errors:

```
C:/React/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/MapView.js
Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.

C:/React/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/decorateMapComponent.js       
Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.

C:/React/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/decorateMapComponent.js       
Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.
```

Comment: Hello, Haley, Did you solve this issue? I am getting same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and finally i realised that this is due to the compatibility of MapView with web browser, you can check it in [Platform Compatibility](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/).
Probably you are trying to run this code in the web browser, so you will have this error due to the MapView import.
I suggest two options:
1- try to add this script to your index.html, replace the API_KEY with your Google Maps API:

```
<script
  async
  defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"
  type="text/javascript"
></script>
```

2-Change the way you test and run the app in some mobile device using expo, normally it will work well.